# Uninstalling a compiled package

Tags: 13.10, make, configure, software-uninstall

I have installed `gambas2_2.23.1.orig.tar.gz` from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gambas2/2.23.1-1ubuntu3 in Ubuntu 13.10, by configuring and then making it.

How can I uninstall it and reverse all changes it has done?

Comment: If it uses autotools, then it should have a `make uninstall` target.

Comment: `make uninstall` does not work when run inside configured folder.

Comment: post the output of `dpkg -l |grep gambas2|awk '{print$2}'`

Comment: @AdityaPatil: `gambas2-runtime` is the output

Comment: Then `sudo apt-get remove gambas2-runtime` should be all you need.

Comment: @AdityaPatil: But it took some time it was installing after `make`. It seems there has been more changes.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus sorry I didn't get your point.Can you reword your first sentence?